# How to query for Mongoid documents by two references

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I'm using Mongoid on this project. Lets say I have a model like so:

```
class Voice

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Enum
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  enum :status, [:enabled, :disabled], :validate => true, :default => :enabled

  ...

  has_and_belongs_to_many                               :categories
  has_and_belongs_to_many                               :builder_types
  has_and_belongs_to_many                               :voice_types
  has_and_belongs_to_many                               :preferences
  has_and_belongs_to_many                               :languages
  embeds_many                                           :comments
  embeds_many                                           :ratings
  belongs_to                                            :artist,                        :class_name => "User"

  ...

end
```

As you can see, `Voice` has and belongs to `Category`, `BuilderType`, `VoiceType` and so on. At the moment, if I want to search for all voices that belongs to a specific category I'd do the following (pseudo code):

```
@category = Category.find(id)
@voices = @category.voices
```

Which works fine. How about search for `Voice` that has or belong to multiple relations and relations type .e.g. (pseudo code that doesn't work):

```
@cat1 = Category.find(id)
@cat2 = Category.find(id)
@voice_type = VoiceType.find(id)
@voices = @cat1.voices.where(category_id: @cat2.id).where(voice_type_id: @voice_type.id)
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas if 1) that's at all possible and 2) how could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, at the end what I did was:

```
@voices = Voice.all(category_ids: [@cat_1.id, @cat_2.id]).
  and(voice_type_ids: @voice_type.id).map{ |voice| voice.format_frontend }
```

Answer (score 1):

This may work out for you:

```
Voice.all(category_ids: [@cat1.id, @cat2.id]).
  where(:voice_type_ids.in [@voice_type.id])
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. It gave me an error: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`